# Correct way of updating a git repository without readding the directories

Tags: git

I apologize if my question is about a very simple topic, and it is answered elsewhere, but I'm a noob with **git**, and I couldn't answer it neither reading the git documentation, nor searching the web.

I've created a git repository for a simple test project. I initialized the repository, added some files and directories using some `git add` commands, and made my first commit.

Just suppose, for example, I've added a README and two directories, `src1` and `src2`, which contain some files. Then suppose I've not just edited the file contents, but I've **added**/removed files in these directories. In order to make the repo up-to-date, I'm currently doing:

```
git add --update
git add src1 src2
git commit -m "something"
```

Please note I'm updating the edited files, and removing the deleted files with `git add --update` and then re-adding the two directories in order to make git track the new files created into them! Is there a simple way (without re-adding) of doing this? I've tried with just:

```
git add --update
git commit -m "something"
```

but this won't add new files that have been created under `src1` and `src2` directories. **That's because git doesn't "remember" I'm tracking an entire directory, but just the files within. git doesn't seem to track directories.**

Obviously I've created a bash script with the lines you see in the above example, but it is a bit cumbersome and I would like to know if there's an easier method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `--update`, use `--all`. See [man git-add](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)

```
git add --all .
```

> That's because git doesn't "remember" I'm tracking an entire directory, but just the files within. git doesn't seem to track directories.

Thats very easy to explain: Yes, you are right :) Git doesn't track directories at all, because directories are not objects in the git-world. Directories don't have any content and there will never be changes to them (because of the missing content), that can git track. If you call `git add path/to/directory` this will not add the directory, but it will add every containing file recursivly.

Just a hint: [TIG](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tig) helped me starting with git quite much :)

Comment: I really don't want to track the whole `.` directory, even if it would be simpler.

Comment: @gd1: That was an example ;) `git add --all src1 src2`, or whatever. What I want to say is, that `--all` (in conjunction with directories) adds new files too.

Answer (score 2):

To add everything you can just run `git add --all`. Git tracks content not files or directories.

If you're using `--all` be careful not to add any unwanted stuff and use a .gitignore.

Comment: Thanks for the .gitignore hint.

Answer (score 1):

git doesn't add new files for a reason. Since not all new files should be in a repository by default. So you either need to add them yourself or create some mechanism that does it for you, but either way it is under your control.

This applies to most version control systems.

Comment: I see. Actually I was not complaining about git behavior, I was just asking why it works this way and how to get along with it. I'll keep on using the bash script.